# English Word that evokes the idea of a collective buying

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for and english word that evokes the idea of the power of buying things together (something like power in numbers).

Comment: Your question is too broad to provide meaningful and specific answers. You should narrow the scope by providing context. So many words evoke the idea of a group that no single answer will be able to cover this as your question is currently written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different terms that could apply and certainly @Little Eva's ***co-op*** is one of them.
Here are some others I found by doing a Google search of "was formed to increase buying power"

***consortium***:

> *Joining a consortium could help increase your buying power and free up overburdened staff resources.* <sup><sub>[Publishing Executive](http://www.pubexec.com/article/join-consortium-increase-buying-power-free-up-staff/1)</sub></sup>
>
> *a consortium of 20 carton manufacturers, have banded together to increase their purchasing power.* <sup><sub>[The Print Suppliers Group](http://www.theprintsuppliersgroup.com/resources/Documents/Print_Suppliers_Group_06.pdf)</sub></sup>

***Collaborative Purchasing***:

> *Collaborative purchasing also reduces the transaction and information costs associated with
>   procurement.* <sup><sub>[The Center for College Affordability](http://www.centerforcollegeaffordability.org/uploads/25_Ways_Ch12.pdf)</sub></sup>

***Group Purchasing Organization (GPO)***:

> *In the United States, a group purchasing organization (GPO) is an entity that is created to leverage the purchasing power of a group of businesses to obtain discounts from vendors based on the collective buying power of the GPO members.* <sub><sup>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_purchasing_organization)</sup></sub>

***Co-op***:

> *Progressive Affiliated Lumbermen (PAL) is a member owned co-op [...] Established in 1934 and incorporated in 1937, PAL was started by 7 independent lumber dealers with the vision to combine their purchases to increase their buying power.* <sub><sup>[National Buying Power](http://www.nationalbuyingpower.com/membership-info/)</sup></sub>

***purchasing coalition***:

> *Geographical purchasing coalitions began forming roughly 10 years ago in order to combine purchases of the most commonly used medical supplies such as exam gloves, syringes, and hospital gowns* <sub><sup>[The Harvard Business Review](https://hbr.org/2014/12/hospital-coalitions-save-money-and-improve-care)</sup></sub>

***purchasing alliance***:

> *Seven systems that include 25 hospitals in New Jersey and Eastern Pennsylvania are banding together in an alliance seeking the benefits of scale without the complications of merging assets. [...] a kind of affiliation that does away with formal integration, and instead focuses on managing population health and increasing their joint purchasing power.*[Modern Health Care](http://www.modernhealthcare.com/article/20130921/MAGAZINE/309219960)

Answer (score 2):

Cooperative purchasing, or a Co-op

> **Co-op** *noun* informal; plural noun: co-ops:
> a cooperative society, business, or enterprise.

From Google [**link**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=co-op+definition&gws_rd=ssl)

> A cooperative ("coop") or co-operative ("co-op") is an autonomous association of people who voluntarily cooperate for their mutual social, economic, and cultural benefit
>
> From wikipedia [**link**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for : to team up

> - form a team; "We teamed up for this new project"
>     (TFD)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for "***collective bargaining***", though this is more typically applied to labor negotiations than outright purchases.